# Design one XIB and re-use it in different UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xib, reusability

I have one `UIView` that I want to use in every of my `UIViewControllers`. The main UI is designed with Storyboard. The extra `UIView` has its own XIB.

So I don't want to put the UI of the extra `UIView` by hand into every `UIViewController`, and connect the outlets on every `UIViewController`. So I thought maybe it is possible to create the UI, and the connections in one XIB and then somehow reuse it. Is this possible? If yes how?

Comment: Isn't the XIB always associated with some specific controller class?

Comment: @KodeCharlie - I believe he's wanting to associate a XIB with a custom `UIView` object, not a `UIViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line to your ViewControllers to have a reference to your custom view:

```
YourView *yourView = (YourView *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourXIB"
                                                               owner:self
                                                             options:nil].firstObject;
```

But since you want this custom view in all of your ViewControllers, I recommend having one `UIViewController` subclass that contains the line above, then subclass that `UIViewController` for each additional one in your project. That way you'll have a reference to your custom view in each ViewController, but only have to write this line once.

Comment: That seems to help, but I got another problem. The IBActions on my UIVIew work perfect. But it seems like the IBOutlets are not initialized. When I check on my UIImageView, the debugger says it is NULL. Why could that be?

Comment: @user1990524 - Your `UIImageView` should be initialized if you created it in your XIB. I would just check over everything and make sure all outlets are connected etc. Try modifying your custom view from the ViewController. If you still can't figure it out, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible by keeping the same name in the function `initWithNibName:`, so you can do this in one of your controller:

```
UIViewController *oneViewController = [[FirstViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyXIBThatWillStayTheSame" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:oneViewController animated:YES];
```

and do this in another one:

```
UIViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyXIBThatWillStayTheSame" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```